# How to determine xscale and yscale programmatically in openlaszlo for different aspect ratios?

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx

I had some problem with stretching the views so finally i used xscale and yscale to scale the view. This problem is solved in my machine which has a resolution

```
canvas.width -1280
canvas.height - 1023
```

in a full screen mode.

But when i check the same in my friends machine whose

```
canvas.width -1280
canvas.height - 697
```

in full screen mode part of the screen is getting cut.

The current scaling factor i have given is xscale = 1.33 and yscale = 1.33. The yscale should be changed in order to fit the second system. How to determine this factor programmatically.

Comment: Does that mean you want to scale a box to min width and height, and to either canvas.width or canvas.height, depending on the aspect ratio of the canvas resolution? And why do you scale, since that's going to increase the size of items on the screen?

Comment: Yes i want to scale the box to a minimum width and height in a way that it is scaled according to different screen size. Earlier i used to give the stretches = true and give  an formula like this for width                                           Debug.write("width", canvas.width/canvas.height &lt; 1.33 
                     ? this.width * this.unstretchedheight/this.unstretchedwidth 
                     : canvas.height);. This will assign a proper width based on the aspect ratio

Comment: @RajuBitter: But this doesn't work in the latest 5.0 or 4.9 because stretches attribute is not getting applied to the subviews. So i have to use xscale or yscale.

Comment: @RajuBitter: In order to support different screens we followed this approach we kept the main view resolution as 800 * 600. And then based on the canvas.width we scaled that main view. 800 * 600 is a least resolution that any pc will definitely support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example code which shows you how to scale a view based on a ratio. The ratio is defined by the unscaledwidth and unscaledheight attributes. There is no implementation for minimum width or minimum height, but it's easy to add that, if you need it.

The disadvantage of this approach is that all the resources will be scaled. In the SWF runtime the resources for the default components are vector based, in the DHTML runtime they are converted to PNG files, and wont look very crisp when scaled. I'd normally not scale the existing OpenLaszlo components, but that's your decision:

```
<canvas width="100%" height="100%">
<!-- OpenLaszlo scaled view example by Raju Bitter -->

    <class name="scaledview">
        <attribute name="unscaledwidth" type="number" value="400"/>
        <attribute name="unscaledheight" type="number" value="300"/>
        <attribute name="wratio" type="number" value="${this.unscaledwidth/this.unscaledheight}"/>

        <handler name="oninit">
            this.setAttribute("width", this.unscaledwidth)
            this.setAttribute("height", this.unscaledheight)
            this._setSize();
        </handler>
        <handler name="onwidth" reference="canvas">
            this._setSize();
        </handler>
        <handler name="onheight" reference="canvas">
            this._setSize();
        </handler>
        <method name="_setSize">
            var scale = 1.0;
            if (canvas.width/canvas.height > this.wratio) {
                scale = canvas.height / this.unscaledheight;
                this.setAttribute("x", Math.round((canvas.width-this.width*scale) / 2));
                this.setAttribute("y", 0);
            } else {
                scale = canvas.width / this.unscaledwidth;
                this.setAttribute("x", 0);
                this.setAttribute("y", Math.round((canvas.height-this.height*scale) / 2));
            }
            this.setAttribute("xscale", scale);
            this.setAttribute("yscale", scale);
        </method>
    </class>

    <scaledview id="sv" bgcolor="red">
       <window width="200" height="100" title="Just a window!" align="center" valign="middle"/>
    </scaledview>

    <view>
        <simplelayout axis="y" />
        <text fontsize="12"
              text="${'canvas: ' + canvas.width + ' * ' + canvas.height + '  ratio=' + (canvas.width/canvas.height)}"/>
        <text fontsize="12"
              text="${'scaledview: ' + sv.width + ' * ' + sv.height + '  ratio=' + sv.wratio}" />
        <text fontsize="12"
              text="${'scaledview: xscale=' + sv.xscale + ' / yscale=' + sv.yscale}" />
    </view>

</canvas>
```

Check the screenshot of the application, where you can see the red <scaledview> scaled based on the ratio defined. The window component will grow and shrink in size with increasing or decreasing canvas resolution.

[image]

Comment: Only test with OpenLaszlo 5.0, in both SWF10 and DHTML. Remember: not all browsers will support scaling of views in DHTML runtime!

Comment: Scaling seems to work pretty good in DHTML runtime, unless you want to use IE9. But then you could always use Flash as fallback.